# Caixa de seleção dependentes

Tags: java, sql, jsf, dropdown, jpql

Estou com um problema e gostaria saber se vocês podem me ajudar.

Eu tenho um CRUD que cadastra ciclos, esses ciclos podem ter muitos cursos.

O que eu queria fazer exatamente, é validar os selectsOneRadios na hora de cadastrar uma questão, ou seja, **escolher um ciclo em um caixa de seleção e na próxima caixa de seleção possibilitar que o usuário cadastre uma questão de um curso que seja desse ciclo escolhido. É mais ou menos, caixa de seleção de Estado e Cidade.**

Segue o código:

QuestaoBean

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CadastroUsuarioBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private UsuarioService usuarioService;

    @Inject
    private GrupoDAO grupoDAO;

    @Inject
    private CursoDAO cursoDAO;

    @Inject
    private FormacaoDAO formacaoDAO;

    private Usuario usuario;
    private List<Grupo> grupos;
    private List<Curso> cursos;
    private List<Formacao> formacoes;


    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        this.limpar();
        this.grupos = grupoDAO.buscaPorTodosGrupos();
        this.cursos = cursoDAO.buscaPorTodosCursos();
        this.formacoes = formacaoDAO.buscaPorTodasFormacoes();


    }

    @Transactional
    public void salvar() throws Exception {
        try {
            this.usuarioService.salvar(usuario);
            FacesUtil
                    .addSuccessMessage("Pré cadastro efetuado com sucesso. Aguarde a aprovação!");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            FacesUtil.addErrorMessage("Erro ao tentar realizar o cadastro!");
        }
        this.limpar();
    }

    private void limpar() {
        this.usuario = new Usuario();
    }

    public List<Grupo> getGrupos() {
        return grupos;
    }

    public List<Curso> getCursos() {
        return cursos;
    }

    public List<Formacao> getFormacoes() {
        return formacoes;
    }

    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }
```

DAO:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Curso> buscarCursoPorCiclo(Long codigo) {
    return  manager
            .createQuery(
                    "select c from Ciclo c JOIN c.cursos a where c.codigo = ?")
            .setParameter(1, codigo).getResultList();
}
```

Página XHTML:

```
<h:panelGrid id="cicloPanelGrid" columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Ciclo" for="ciclo" style="font-weight:bold" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="ciclo"
                        value="#{cadastroQuestaoBean.questao.ciclo}"
                        converter="cicloConverter" required="true"
                        requiredMessage="Preencha o Ciclo">
                        <p:ajax event="change" process="@this ciclo" update="curso" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione..." />
                        <f:attribute name="collectionType" value="java.util.ArrayList" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroQuestaoBean.ciclos}" var="ciclo"
                            itemLabel="#{ciclo.descricao}" itemValue="#{ciclo}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </h:panelGrid>

                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel value="Curso" for="curso" style="font-weight:bold" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu  id="curso" 
                        value="#{cadastroQuestaoBean.questao.curso}"
                        converter="cursoConverter" required="true"
                        requiredMessage="Preencha o curso">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione..." />
                        <f:attribute name="collectionType" value="java.util.ArrayList" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroQuestaoBean.cursos}" var="curso"
                            itemLabel="#{curso.nome}" itemValue="#{curso}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </h:panelGrid>
```

ERRO:

**itemLabel="#{curso.nome}": Property 'nome' not found on type com.sisEnade.tcc.modelo.Ciclo**

Comment: Poste todo o seu managed bean e a classe curso também. Isso vai ajudar para que alguém possa ajudar a encontrar a solução.

Comment: Pronto Weslley Tavares.

Comment: Onde você define o bean 'cadastroQuestaoBean'?

Comment: Define em qual sentindo? Se for em questão de camada é uma controller se for em questão de chamar ela, usar ela é no xhtml.

Comment: Como o seu erro descreve de forma clara, o problema está ocorrendo no momento que a sua aplicação faz uma chamada a uma determinada propriedade de um objeto, porém, não tá conseguindo ter acesso a esse atributo. Seria bom se você postasse todas as classes que estão envolvidas nessa chamada em cadeia.